# How to replace text with another text in javascript on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, pageload

I have an html inspect code as shown below:

```
<time datetime="07:05 13-06-2020" data-area="ab">13 June <span>07:05</span></time>
```

The above html inspect prints the following on webpage:

**13 June**

What I want to achieve is instead of **13 June**, it should display **13 Juin** on page load.

This is what I have tried but its replacing the **13 June** with **Juin**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("time").replaceWith("Juin");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the entire `time` element by using [`.replaceWith`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). Instead, you need to change the inner HTML of the `time` tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("time").html($("time").html().replace('June', 'Juin'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<time datetime="07:05 13-06-2020" data-area="ab">13 June <span>07:05</span></time>
```

Comment: hi, I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540910/revoke-write-access-for-a-particular-user-in-php?noredirect=1#comment110602058_62540910). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look. What I want to achieve is when one user (UserA) is logged in and another user (UserB) tries to login at the same time then UserA should not be allowed to save the form meaning we are revoking the write access for UserA.

Answer (score 2):

One more way how you can do that

```js
window.onload = function(){
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0];
   a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(/June/,'Juin');
};
```

```html
<time datetime="07:05 13-06-2020" data-area="ab">13 June <span>07:05</span></time>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o60x7q83/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("time").html($("time").html().replace('June', 'Juin'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> low explained about "Javascript" in Jquery is other syntax onload can load on body as reference to this function

```
(function(e) {
e.preventDefault;

 function startTime() {
 var today = new Date();
 var h = today.getHours();
 var m = today.getMinutes();
 var s = today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
 m = checkTime(m);
 s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var t = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {
 i = "0" + i;
 }
 return i;
 }
}())
```